# Manga about a kid who got powers of Buddha

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm not sure about the specifics but the most memorable characters to me are the following:

Grandma who reverted back to being young but kept the powers of another Buddha.
Guy who has healing powers but bashes a brick on the wounded area to heal it.

Grandma who went back to being young is helping the MC to master his powers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please take a look at the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335), and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: What powers does the Buddha have?  Doesn't giving the Buddha superpowers kind of miss the point?

Comment: I believe the grandma was able to control a type of Buddha, like Bodhitsattva or something along the line.

Comment: @Buzz - That's Mahayana Buddhism for you....

Comment: This reminds me a little of the (English language version of the) Japanese folk tale "Three Strong Women".